# Type not found in PowerShell session: "Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AppxPackage"

Tags: powershell, types

Below is example variable which once entered into PowerShell Core reports that the type was not found:

```
[Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AppxPackage] $test = $null
```

> InvalidOperation: Unable to find type
> [Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AppxPackage].

However once you run the following code:

```
Get-AppxPackage -PackageTypeFilter Main
```

Then the previous variable declaration will be just fine (no error):

```
[Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AppxPackage] $test = $null
```

How do I make this type get recognized by PowerShell session without running `Get-AppxPackage`?

I tried with `using namespace Microsoft.Windows` and few other namespaces but it doesn't work.

Environment data:

```
$PSVersionTable 

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.0.3
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.0.3
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19041
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, at the top of your script add this line:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands
```

Now we can use all the types from that assembly:

```
[Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.AppxPackage] $test = $null
```

No error.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-7)